# Vertex slide for curves?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Is there a vertex/edge slide like tool for curves?

In other words, I'd like to be able to edit the curve in the same way I can with a mesh, by sliding a vertex along a connecting edge:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Straightforward way, no (currently). But possible to make it in another way.

If the cuve is as simple as a poly spline, I think you can try converting it to a mesh first, tweak it with Vertex Slide tool, then convert back to curve, but the original paramters on curve may lose then. Or:

1. Select the target curve point, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to New Object*;
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>Convert the curve in to mesh object;
3. <kbd>Tab</kbd> in to the Edit Mode, select the target vertex, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> to select the hook (a empty object) while still in Edit Mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > to make vertex parent. Then you can slide that vertex in the mesh to control the target curve point.

Another way is to use the handle orientation as transformation reference:

1. Be sure to switch Spline Type to **Bezier**, then set handle type to **Vector**;
2. Switch Transformation Orientation to **Normal**, then select the handle control point, create transformation orientation from it;
3. Now select the curve point, you can move it along Z axis of the new orientation.
4. When finished, you may want to delete the created orientation(s).

[image]

Comment: I guess this is a close as one can get currently.. Not as fast as I might have hoped (I think I can manually position it with G before I finish setting up the custom orientation :P). But thanks for the answer :D

Comment: I'm also wondering if there are any other ways to do this, and I do believe someone can make addon for it, even to support sliding along curvature, but would be even better to implement indeed, since it brings more convenience for those who are taking topology workflow by using curves first. (similar to BSurfaces)

Answer (score 4):

Found something very close. Within addons, turn on **experimental**, go into **Add Curve: Simple Curve**. Turn on addon. Go into **miscellaneous** tab of the tool shelf. Click **divide**. Go down to the tool settings panel below on the same side. Change percentage value.

This is the closest I can get trying to find an intersect of 2 curves. Blender is in need of various CAD tools specifically for curves.

Answer (score 2):

This might help : as seen on [this post](https://blenderartists.org/t/vertex-slide-on-curves-asking-for-a-friend-no-really/1351623/4),
you can use the *curve tools* addon shipped with Blender to subdive along path:

[image]