# Bezier Curve - Evenly space a bezier curve, without losing the curvy-ness

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves

I am currently working on a project, in which I need a bezier curve to act as a path. The path needs to be as smooth as possible, and I cant affort to lose any of it.

I also need to space out the bezier curve, so that its evenly spaced everywhere ( cause of speed inside the other application ). I used looptools for this before, however this requires your curve to be mesh, which results in losing curvy-ness.

Might someone have a solution for this? Either by a feature of blender, a simple tutorial or a python script? Please let me know. Have been looking for a good solution for half a year already, so Thought it might be time to ask some questions haha.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-evenly-space-vertices-along-several-segments-bezier-curve ?

Comment: Since its an old topic, and hasnt included any python scripting into it, I guess this topic can stay? As the old one isnt used I suppose