# Evenly distribute vertices in bezier curve

Tags: vertices, bezier-curves

In Blender 2.79, evenly distributing vertices using LoopTools only seems to work for meshes, not bezier curves. How would one do it for bezier curves? I have seen this post: [How to evenly space vertices along several segments bezier curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-evenly-space-vertices-along-several-segments-bezier-curve) but find the first solution too much of a workaround. The second solution does not work for me, because Blender does NOT place new vertices in the exact middle between existing vertices when subdividing a bezier curve (see screenshot)
[image]

Comment: It shouldn't place vertices unevenly when you subdivide a bezier curve, it should place the new vertices exactly between existing vertices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evenly space vertices along several segments bezier curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-evenly-space-vertices-along-several-segments-bezier-curve) Check my second answer there

Comment: @moonboots Somehow, it doesn't (see edited question). Could I have messed up any settings in Blender? I opened a new file for the screenshot.

Comment: @Duarte I have seen that post but find the first answer unsatisfying and the second answer does not work for me (see edited question).

Comment: Anne, you're right I've never noticed that, I guess I haven't used bezier curves a lot  ;)

Comment: I use curves frequently and that never seen that happened subdividing always places vertex at the center. Try checking if your Bézier curve is set to 2D and that there are no duplicate vertex overlapping. Also see if your handles aren't skewing the results

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Subdividing bezier segments in Blender places the points evenly in relation to the [time parameter when moving along the curve](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/db/B%C3%A9zier_3_big.gif/240px-B%C3%A9zier_3_big.gif). It does not take spacial distances into account. The fact it worked for you is only a coincidence and rare, it depends on the curve shape and how long the handles are. In general those segments are not even, the arch lengths between points differ.

Comment: @Duarte indeed, when I select a vertex including its handles and scale it down to zero (by hitting S, then 0), the new vertex appears in the middle between the existing vertices. I guess this will have to be good enough for now.

Comment: @Jaroslav thanks for clearing that up. It explains the "weird" behaviour of vertices. My only experience with vertices coming from static vector illustration software (Inkscape, Illustrator), getting used to Blender's four dimensions can be hard for me.