# How to evenly space curve vertices?

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I convert one edge of the mesh to a curve.
I want to distribute mesh on the curve by using curve modifier
but it won't space it evenly
because the curve vertices aren't evenly spaced.
How to fix that?
[image][image]

Comment: I don't know if it exists forcurves, you could convert to mesh, use LoopTools >Space, then convert to curve again?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-evenly-space-vertices-along-several-segments-bezier-curve

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to try is to use Geometry Nodes to resample the curve:

[image]

Keep in mind you won't see the circles (spheres) in the preview, I added another geonodes tree afterwards for that.

You can't apply the geometry nodes modifier on the curve. But what you can do is select the object, <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> *Visual Geometry to Mesh*. Then <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for `convert curve`.

The preview node tree (you want to **disable it** before applying the modifiers) used:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Enable the built-in addon called [`LoopTools`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/looptools.html) via menu *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > LoopTools*. You can evenly space your vertices in a mesh by selecting all vertices in *Edit Mode* and then right click or <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *LoopTools > Space*. If you have a curve, first convert it to mesh and then do the *LoopTools > Space* and convert back to curve.

[image]