# Edge Slide or divide Curve section into unequal cuts?

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

I know I can subdivide between two curve vertices to get a new vertex exactly in the middle of them, but is there a way to either create a control point NOT right in the middle from the get-go (e.g. one point 1/3 of the way) OR "edge-slide" the curve vertex to a different position? Thanks!

Comment: checkout this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24153/vertex-slide-for-curves

Comment: Helpful, thanks! A shame that Blender hasn't come up with something more intuitive here yet.

Comment: I don‘t think it is a shame. Don‘t forget: the software is free…

Comment: True that. I just thought if Blender is able to be developed by anyone (competent enough to make plugins), someone would've made one already. Still, your answer is probably what I'll end up using!

Comment: So i am happy i could help 